# Flink ReadCsvFile ParserError NUMERIC_VALUE_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER

Tags: scala, csv, apache-flink

I am trying to read Iris DataSet into flink with its [readCsvFile function](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.flink.api.scala.ExecutionEnvironment@readCsvFile[T](filePath:String,lineDelimiter:String,fieldDelimiter:String,quoteCharacter:Character,ignoreFirstLine:Boolean,ignoreComments:String,lenient:Boolean,includedFields:Array[Int],pojoFields:Array[String])(implicitevidence$1:scala.reflect.ClassTag[T],implicitevidence$2:org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[T]):org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet[T]) and I keep getting `ParserError NUMERIC_VALUE_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER`

The csv (With hidden chars visible) is like this

[image]

I've tried to remove the whitespaces between items in the file, without luck. There are multiple items that can not be read, this is the error output:

```
org.apache.flink.api.common.io.ParseException: Line could not be parsed: '5.4, 3.0, 4.5, 1.5, 2'
ParserError NUMERIC_VALUE_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER 
Expect field types: class java.lang.Long, class java.lang.Long, class java.lang.Long, class java.lang.Long, class java.lang.Integer 
in file: /home/hkr/Documents/Estudios/Máster/TFM/Desarrollo/DPASF/dpasf/target/scala-2.11/test-classes/iris.dat
[...]
org.apache.flink.api.common.io.ParseException: Line could not be parsed: '4.5, 2.3, 1.3, 0.3, 1'
ParserError NUMERIC_VALUE_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER
[...]
```

But when I inspect those rows, I found no strange character, only those in the image below.

[image]

I've tried different things:

```
// Iris POJO
case class Iris(SepalLength:Long,
  SepalWidth:Long,
  PetalLength:Long,
  PetalWidth:Long,
  Class:Int)

val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val dataSet = env.readCsvFile[Iris](getClass.getResource("/iris.dat").getPath, "\n", ",")
```

And differents combinations of this, like changing `Class` attr to `Long`, or using a Tuple5, and also using readCsvFile with defaults args:

```
val dataSet = env.readCsvFile[(Long, Long, Long, Long, Long)](getClass.getResource("/iris.dat").getPath)
val dataSet = env.readCsvFile[(Long, Long, Long, Long, Int)](getClass.getResource("/iris.dat").getPath)
```

Does anybody knows what may be happening? I do not know where to look anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason it seems to be working now after replacing all rows with a new line again, and then removing all white spaces from the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the white space before and after the delimeter can help solve this problem.